# Cannot find include error on unix server (although I cannot see why it is upper case )

Tags: php, unix, yii, include, case-sensitive

I am getting the following error on my Yii setup on our UNIX server:

```
include(MyAppApiController.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

It would appear that it isn't working because it is case-sensitive on the server, but I have looked through the code and it only ever appears as lower case sensitive. Can anyone give me any idea why it would be doing this??

P.S it works in my windows environment fine hence why I only found this error on our unix server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot quotation makrs in your code. 
Change `include(MyAppApiController.php)`
to
`include "MyAppApiController.php";`

Hope it answers your question.